# Chamar função em $state.go() Ionic/Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para chamar uma função que está em outro controlador exemplo:

Estou na view de 'Cadastro' e apos fazer um cadastro eu sou redirecionado para `view` 'Home' no `controller` da Home eu tenho uma função que recebe um parâmetro.

Tem como chamar a função da Home passando um parâmetro estando em Cadastro?

Exemplo:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.myFunction = function(valor) {

    alert(valor);

  }
})

.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.add = function() {
    $state.go('tab.home');
    //Ir para tela Home e chamar a função myFunction('teste')
    //passando 'teste' como parãmtro 
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

    $rootScope.myFunction = function(valor) {

       alert(valor);

    }
})

.controller('AddCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

   $scope.add = function(valor) {

      $state.go('tab.home').then(function(){

          $rootScope.myFunction(valor);

      });
   }

 })
```

$rootScope fica acessível em todos os controllers

Comment: Poxa André Vicente, achei esta solução muito boa e prática! Obrigado amigo, isto resolve o meu caso. Valeu!!

Answer (score 0):

Configure sua rota para aceitar um parâmetro opcional:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab.home', {
        url: "/home/:parm",
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            var parm = $stateParams.parm;
        }
    })
```

E, para navegar para este *state* passando o parâmetro -

```
$state.go('tab.home/teste');
```